# Writing avro files with apache spark/on prem hadoop TO google cloud storage

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to migrate some spark workflows using on premesis hadoop to google cloud storage.

Assuming VPC, networking, cloud interconnect, and firewalls are all in order, how would one first go about writing avro files (currently in parquet) to an external destination such as google cloud storage? What considerations must one make when using oozie & spark-submit for example? Do I need to map google cloud storage as a location? We want to get away from storing things in HDFS, but right now all the workflow destinations are writing into hadoop right now.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [DistCp](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/hadoop/hadoop-gcp-migration-data#using_distcp_to_copy_your_data_to_cloud_storage) rather than Spark for existing data, and configure oozie to run that.

For new/existing Spark jobs, you will need the [Cloud Storage Connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/hadoop-connectors/tree/master/gcs) and configure it in Spark's `core-site.xml`, then you should be able to write a dataframe to GCS

```
val dataframe = spark.read.load("hdfs://some/data") // existing parquet files

dataframe.write
    .format("avro")
    .save("gs://bucket/path")
```

[Spark Avro data sources](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-avro.html#to_avro-and-from_avro)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The existing spark jobs are all on-prem. For now, that must remain. Is the link you've placed above, for the connector, a proposed solution if spark is to remain external?

Comment: It shouldnt matter where Spark is running, but if running in DataProc, it'll automatically have all the necessary classpath and authentication needed for GCS (depending on IAM roles). https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/hadoop-connectors/blob/master/gcs/INSTALL.md#configuring-spark

Comment: Instead of parquet we'd want it switched to avro. I see the numerous advantages of dataproc but can tell it's not operable for this use-case for now I guess.

Comment: I understood your question, as answered, you'd just use `.format("avro")` to write to that format. Loading data defaults to Parquet. DataProc is a runtime environment for Hadoop jobs on GCP, and isn't related to what you're asking other than it already is setup to use GCS. I.e. use Dataproc to _**pull** your on-prem data_ into GCS